# IE 11 not understanding the common method, giving undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, sharepoint

I have defined a common function in a js file with the name as spMethods which is a common function which has some other function in it.

It is defined as :

```
var spMethods = function () {  
   function getContext() {  
        return new SP.ClientContext(appweburl);  
    }  
    function getAppContextSite(ctx) {  
        var fct = new SP.ProxyWebRequestExecutorFactory(appweburl);  
        ctx.set_webRequestExecutorFactory(fct);  
        return new SP.AppContextSite(ctx, hostweburl);  
    }  
};
```

now when i am trying to use this same function in other js file it is giving me undefined for spMethods

Comment: Is that only occurs on IE11?

Comment: yes.. it is happening in IE11 only

Comment: how did you imported the js file?

Comment: as a script tag, actually this is a project in react which I am building in visual studio 2017

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To define the global function in the common.js file use below given syntax.

```
  var globalFn= window.globalFn || {};
    globalFn.spMethods = globalFn.spMethods || {};
```

To use this spMethods function in any other component js file use below given syntax.
for example in 'abc.js':

```
var _globalFn = window.globalFn|| {};
var _spMethodsClerk = new _globalFn.spMethods();
```

once _spMethodsClerk  object is instantiated you will get other methods defined in it. Like `getContext()` and `getAppContextSite()` etc.

Let me know if that helps?

Answer (score 2):

You could create your library file like this:

```
export function getContext() {
    return "getContext()";
};

export function getAppContextSite(ctx) {
    return "getContext(" + ctx + ")";
};
```

And use it in this way:

```
import * as spMethods from './test';
{spMethods.getContext()}
```

See the working example on [codesandbox.io](https://codesandbox.io/s/k0mpl686l3).

Comment: My project is in Visual Studio 2017  so cant use import

Comment: What do you mean? `import` is an ECMA definition from 2015, how is VS 2017 relevant?